# php Class to Json expected to return only set values

Tags: php, oop

I have a class with multiple properties, all of which are optional, but can accept empty or null as a value. When converting the class to a JSON object, I require it to return only those properties of the class which are being set.

I can't filter then the final result since the value can be null or empty which is a valid entry. So in short, I want only those properties for whose setter functions had been called.

```
<?php    
class MyClass{

public $property1;
public $property2;
public $property3;
public $property4;
public $property5;

public function setProperty1($property1){
    $this->property1 = $property1;
    return $this;
}

public function setProperty2($property2){
    $this->property2 = $property2;
    return $this;
}

public function setProperty3($property3){
    $this->property3 = $property3;
    return $this;
}

public function setProperty4($property4){
    $this->property4 = $property4;
    return $this;
}

public function setProperty5($property5){
    $this->property5 = $property5;
    return $this;
}
}

$obj = new MyClass();
$obj->setProperty1("p1");
$obj->setProperty2("");
$obj->setProperty3(null);
echo json_encode($obj);
```

**Output:**`{"property1":"p1","property2":"","property3":null,"property4":null,"property5":null}`

**Expected:**
`{"property1":"p1","property2":"","property3":null}`

Comment: Remove the block where you declare `public $property1;` ... `public $property6;` and you get your expected result

Comment: There is not much sense in using a class for something like this. Just use an associative array and declare the keys as you need them.